# Refreshing a graph displayed by UIView

Tags: iphone

I have a Tabbar App of which the Root views are UITableviews (different classes).

On one of the UITableviews has a sub class UIView on which I draw a graph with drawRect, but at times the graph is not updated properly and has incorrect/ old information .

How I can refresh the graph on the UIView with eg setNeedsDisplay from external classes?

Will appreciate any input to resolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

1. Don't need to refresh the UIView from other classes.
2. Just make sure that you call setNeedsDisplay from the class that UIView is sub classed in.

Walla